# Is label smoothing equivalent to adding a KL divergence term or a cross entropy term?

Tags: neural-networks, kullback-leibler, cross-entropy

In the context of cross-entropy loss objectives for neural networks, I tend to think of label smoothing from the standpoint of directly manipulating the labels. This [blog post](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Label-Smoothing) explains how doing so is equivalent to adding an extra loss term, that is the the cross-entropy loss between the uniform noise distribution and the model output distribution:

\begin{align}L^\prime &= \sum_{i=1}^n\left\{(1-\varepsilon)\left[-\sum_{y=1}^Kp(y|x_i)\log q_\theta(y|x_i)\right]+\varepsilon\left[-\sum_{y=1}^Ku(y|x_i)\log q_\theta(y|x_i)\right]\right\}\\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n\left [(1-\varepsilon)H_i(p,q_\theta)+ \varepsilon H_i(u, q_\theta)\right]\end{align}

I can follow this just fine.

But when I look at [Regularizing Neural Networks By Penalizing Confident Output Distributions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.06548.pdf), it talks about the extra term being a KL divergence instead (see section 3.2). In the latter case, I can't make the connection.

I have a [related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/520995/how-do-we-get-from-entropy-to-kl-divergence-in-this-paper) on this.

**But now I'm just totally confused about whether label smoothing is equivalent to adding a cross entropy term, or if it's equivalent to adding a KL divergence term.**

Answer (score 3):

You are just one step away! Following Lei Mao's derivation $\eqref{eq1}$, we can replace the second term in the right hand with $\eqref{eq2}$.
$$L^{'} = \sum_{i=1}^n \left[ (1-\epsilon)H_i(p, q_\theta) + \epsilon H_i(u, q_\theta)\right] \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
$$H(u, q) = D_{KL}(u || q) + H(u) \tag{2} \label{eq2}$$
Voilà, we have $\eqref{eq3}$ in which the term $H(u)$ is a constant during the optimization when $u$ is a uniform distribution. Therefore, we can neglect it. Eventually, $\eqref{eq4}$ is what the paper [Regularizing Neural Networks By Penalizing Confident Output Distributions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.06548.pdf) actually refers to.
$$L^{'} = \sum_{i=1}^n \left[ (1-\epsilon)H_i(p, q_\theta) + \epsilon D_{KL}(u || q_\theta) + \epsilon H(u) \right] \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$
$$L^{'} = \sum_{i=1}^n \left[ (1-\epsilon)H_i(p, q_\theta) + \epsilon D_{KL}(u || q_\theta) \right] \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$
However, the equation in Section 3.2 of the paper [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.06548.pdf) omitted the smoothing factor for unknown reasons. It would be more understandable if reformulated as $\eqref{eq5}$ which is quite close to $\eqref{eq4}$. Hope this clarifies your confusion ;)
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
L(\theta) &= - \sum \left[ \text{log} q_{\theta}(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x}) - D_{KL}(u || q_\theta (\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x})) \right] \\
          &= \sum \left[ - \text{log} q_{\theta}(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x}) + D_{KL}(u || q_\theta (\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x})) \right] \\
          &= \sum \left[ H(p, q_\theta(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x})) + D_{KL}(u || q_\theta (\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{x})) \right]
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5}$$
Last but not least, back to your final question, both of your statements hold when the noise distribution $u$ is a uniform distribution.

Comment: Thanks! This was over a year ago so I'll need to find some time to have a look at it again before accepting your answer, but it seems like you got it :)